# ORA:00933 SQL Command Not Properly Ended Error, while syncing Oracle and SQL Databases through C#.Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to update a table from Oracle Database to a table in SQL Server. But I'm getting an error:

> ORA-00933 SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED.

I've tried every way to deal with it but not getting any solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OleDbConnection conOracle = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conOracle.Open();
    SqlConnection conSql = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    conSql.Open();

    //data set for Updation in CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN Table in SQL

    DataSet dsCWS = new DataSet();
    string strUPDCWS = "SELECT SERIALNUMBER, GROUPCODE, PARTNO, RECCHALLANNO, RECDATE, FROMBRANCH, ";
    strUPDCWS += " RECHUB, DEFSRNO, OKSRNO, FCRNO, FCRDATE, RECDTYPE, SEQNUMBER ";
    strUPDCWS += " FROM CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN WHERE INSFLG='N' ";
    OleDbCommand cmdUPDCWS = new OleDbCommand(strUPDCWS, conOracle);
    OleDbDataAdapter adpUPDCWS = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adpUPDCWS.SelectCommand = cmdUPDCWS;
    adpUPDCWS.Fill(dsCWS, "table1");

    //DataSet dsSqlUPDCWS = new DataSet();
    string strSQLUPDCWS = "";
    string OLEupdCWS = "";
    if (dsCWS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow i in dsCWS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            try
            {

                strSQLUPDCWS = "UPDATE CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN SET GROUPCODE='" + i["GROUPCODE"].ToString().Trim() + "', PARTNO='" + i["PARTNO"].ToString().Trim() + "',";
                strSQLUPDCWS += " RECCHALLANNO='" + i["RECCHALLANNO"].ToString().Trim() + "',RECDATE='" + i["RECDATE"].ToString().Trim() + "',FROMBRANCH='" + i["FROMBRANCH"].ToString().Trim() + "',RECHUB='" + i["RECHUB"].ToString().Trim() + "',";
                strSQLUPDCWS += " DEFSRNO='" + i["DEFSRNO"].ToString().Trim() + "',OKSRNO='" + i["OKSRNO"].ToString().Trim() + "',FCRNO='" + i["FCRNO"].ToString().Trim() + "',FCRDATE='" + i["FCRDATE"].ToString().Trim() + "',RECDTYPE='" + i["RECDTYPE"].ToString().Trim() + "',SERIALNUMBER='" + i["SERIALNUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "'";
                strSQLUPDCWS += " WHERE SEQNUMBER='" + i["SEQNUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "'";
                SqlCommand cmdUPDSqlCWS = new SqlCommand(strSQLUPDCWS, conSql);
                cmdUPDSqlCWS.ExecuteNonQuery();

               //Updating Flag in Oracle Database

                OLEupdCWS = "UPDATE CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN SET INSFLG='Y' AND INSDATE = SYSDATE WHERE SEQNUMBER='" + i["SEQNUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmdOraceUpd = new OleDbCommand(OLEupdCWS, conOracle);
                cmdOraceUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SEQNUMBER is number or varchar?? does both SQL and Oracle Update command gives same error??

Comment: Are you getting the error on the `SELECT` or the `UPDATE`?  Is there a reason that you're not using bind variables?  Have you printed out the SQL statement that throws the error so you can see exactly what you have dynamically constructed?

Comment: Please use parameters instead of that way to avoid SQL injections ;).

Comment: I guess the error is in update part of SQL statement, as it is catching the exception.

Comment: OK.  Which of the two updates is failing?  Have you printed out the SQL statement that throws the error so you can see exactly what you have dynamically constructed?

Comment: SEQNUMBER is NUMBER type in Oracle and Numeric(18,0) in SQL Database.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your suggestion. I found out that there was an error in my last update statement of Oracle. 'SET INSFLG='Y' AND INSDATE = SYSDATE'

Comment: @SameepBaxi: Since the error you found is the one I pointed out in my answer, you should either accept it or delete the question so that people will know that the problem is solved, Unless, of course, the problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this row:

```
OLEupdCWS = "UPDATE CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN SET INSFLG='Y' AND INSDATE = SYSDATE WHERE SEQNUMBER='" + i["SEQNUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "'";
```

Should be this:

```
OLEupdCWS = "UPDATE CwsFaultyOracleSqlSYN SET INSFLG='Y' WHERE SEQNUMBER='" + i["SEQNUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "' AND INSDATE = SYSDATE ";
```

Note: your `AND` was before the `WHERE`.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you really should use parameters when dealing with databases, unless you want a visit from [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).